# Dart - Distinguish between sync and async void callbacks

Tags: asynchronous, dart, future, void, synchronous

Suppose we have the following method:

```
Future<String> foo(void callback()) async{
    ...
    callback();
    ...
}
```

Then the **callback** is allowed to be either sync or async when defined. Is there a clean way to **await** it if it is async? Now if I await it here I get this warning from IDE:

> 'await' applied to 'void', which is not a 'Future'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  The whole point of making an `async` function return `void` instead of `Future<void>` is so that the function is "fire-and-forget" and so that the caller *can't* wait for it to complete.

If you want to allow your `foo` function to take asynchronous functions as arguments, then its parameter should be a `Future<void> Function()` instead.  That way callers can easily adapt a synchronous function with an asynchronous wrapper. (The reverse is not possible.)

Alternatively you could make the `callback` parameter return a `FutureOr<void>`:

```dart
Future<String> foo(FutureOr<void> Function callback) async {
    ...
    await callback();
    ...
}
```

or if you don't want an unnecessary `await` if `callback` is synchronous:

```dart
Future<String> foo(FutureOr<void> Function callback) async {
    ...
    if (callback is Future<void> Function) {
      await callback();
    } else {
      callback();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I use Future<void> callback(), then I get the warning [This function has a return type of 'Future<void>', but doesn't end with a return statement], which means that I should use async keyword every time calling foo. So in Either way I might get some warnings, but you propose that the Future way is more clear from the caller's perspective, right?

Comment: I'd use `FutureOr<void>` in this case. It's a parameter, so the pain of dealing with the optionally-asynchronous result rests on the author of the function with that parameter, not the user of the function. It's OK to give yourself more work. Don't return a `FutureOr` from your API, that's pushing the trouble onto your users. Just return a future.

Comment: @navid Yes, I was suggesting that callers could wrap synchronous callbacks in `() async => originalCallback()`.  I've also updated my answer with `FutureOr` examples.